# zk getStyle function doen't get the latest position after the user dragged the component

Tags: javascript, java, mvvm, zk

I plan to catch the position after users' dragging step. However, when I　tried to call getStyle (zk's function)(I also did some splitting action), the function only reflects the original, the before-dragged position of the component.

I am using zk 8.5.0
P.S. the getStyle output something like top:##px;left##px

```
        Connection conn = DaoDataSource.getConnection();
        for(int i =0;i<currentDiv.size();i++) { 
            Div ithDiv = currentDiv.get(i);
            top = ithDiv.getStyle().split(";")[0].split(":")[1].split("px")[0];
            left = ithDiv.getStyle().split(";")[1].split(":")[1].split("px")[0];
            String query = "UPDATE "+tablename+" SET LEFT ="+left+",Top="+top+" WHERE ID = "
                        +ithDiv.getId().split("-")[1]; 
            System.out.println(query);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            st.close();

        }


        conn.close();
```

expected result,for example: UPDATE monitorposition SET LEFT =41,Top=226 WHERE ID = 1
actual,the unwanted result: UPDATE monitorposition SET LEFT =10,Top=106 WHERE ID = 1 
(by unwanted, I'm meaning it returns the original undragged coordinates)

Comment: When you execute this code, is that when the drag event is completly over? You can check in the dom if they values also really change after dragging

Comment: I'm grateful for your reply!!! I'll take this into consideration.